# How to disable Script Template validation in Visual Studio/Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jquery-templates, web-essentials

I have a Script Template where I use jQuery.tmpl Variables:

```
<script id="BC_Template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div class="BC_AddBContainer" style="left: ${left}; bottom: ${bottom}"></div>
</script>
```

Visual Studio or Web Essentials (2013), I don't know which one, complains about problems with the code in the `style` Attribute. I thought Script Templates are ignored from being parsed?

[image: Warnings from Visual Studio 2013]

How can I disable these warnings but only for Script Templates? Web Essentials and/or Lint Script Comment disabling (or whatever it is called) did not work here.